# GraalVM native missing kafka clients OAuthBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, graalvm

I am trying to create a GraalVM compiled native executable connecting to kafka using org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka. In plain java everything works fine. After compiling into native executable it fails to start throwing:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: 
Could not find a public no-argument constructor for 
org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler
```

I've tried reflect-config.json as well as graalvm-reachability-metadata. Both to no avail. I couldn't find any working instruction via google, hence this post.
I am using spring-boot 3.1.3.

Comment: The error says nothing about `OAuthBearerSaslClientCallbackHandler` being *missing*. Do you have the correct library versions?

Comment: As I wrote - it works in plain java.

Comment: Please provide all your GraalVM config files, CLI parameters, etc... (and/or Spring Boot native config) The error comes probably from GraalVM removing something you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GraalVM's native image agent:

```
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=PATH_TO_YOUR_SPRING_BOOT_PROJECT\src\main\resources\META-INF\native-image -jar PATH_TO_YOUR_SPRING_BOOT_PROJECT\target\NAME_OF_FAT_JAR.jar
```

It will produce reachability files in your project's resources folder. Then build your project using org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin. The plugin will automatically pick up the files produced by the agent if you save them in resources\META-INF. If you still get missing classes, resources etc. during the execution - repeat the run. It will merge newly found information with previously created files.
Very rudimentary documentation can be found here: https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/

Comment: thank you for answering this question, Matthias. To add a bit to what you said, the up to date documentation is here: https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/
and here are docs from the Native Maven plugin perspective: https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html#agent-support-running-application